# Test Report is not generating using 'protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter'

Tags: protractor

I am using POM concepts and all the instructions given :
https://npm.runkit.com/protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter
https://github.com/bcole/protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/README.md

but still no reports is generating. Is that anything I am lacking. Earlier I have used 'protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter' and it was working fine.

Console output I am getting is correct on running protractor conf.js using cmd:
4 specs, 3 failures
Finished in 32.847 seconds

[11:32:40] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[11:32:40] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:32:40] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 3 test(s)
[11:32:40] I/launcher - overall: 3 failed spec(s)
[11:32:40] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

**Project Structure**:
[**Project Structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpEF1.png)

**pages/AllevaHome.js**

```
  var AllevaHomePage = function() {

  var logoutBtn = element(by.className('logoutbtn'));

  this.isLogoutDisplays = function(){

    var flag = logoutBtn.isDisplayed();
    return flag

 };

  this.logout = function(){

    logoutBtn.click();

     };
};

module.exports = new AllevaHomePage();
```

**pages/AllevaLogin.js**

```
 var AllevaLoginPage = function() {

 var username = element(by.model('LoginViewModel.UserName'));<br>
 var password = element(by.model('LoginViewModel.Password'));<br>
 var loginBtn = element(by.className('orange-btn login_btn'));<br>
 var securityAns = element(by.model('twoFactorModel.answer'));<br>
 var proceedBtn = element(by.css('[value="Proceed"]'));<br>

this.get = function() {
  browser.get('some url');
  browser.manage().window().maximize();
};




function setUsername(user){

  username.sendKeys(user);

};



  function setPassword(pass){

  password.sendKeys(pass);

 };



   function setAnswer(ans){

      securityAns.sendKeys(ans);

  };

 this.login = function(user, pass, ans){

   setUsername(user);
   setPassword(pass);
   loginBtn.click();
   setAnswer(ans);
   proceedBtn.click();

 };

   /* this.getGreetingText = function() {
    return greeting.getText();
 };*/


 };

 module.exports = new AllevaLoginPage();
```

**testdata/LoginData.js**

```
  'use strict';

   module.exports = {

   LoginData: {

    'Valid Username/Password': {username: 'someuser', password: 'somepass', 
     answer: 'someans'},

    'Invalid Username/Correct Password': {username: 'testuser', password: 
    'Test@12345', answer: 'kusum'},

    'Invalid Username/Invalid Password': {username: 'testuser', password: 
    'Test@1234', answer: 'kusum'},

    'Valid Username/Invalid Password': {username: 'rohitnegi', password: 
    'Test@1234', answer: 'kusum'}

    }
 }
```

**tests/AllevaLoginTest.js**

```
  var AllevaLoginObj = require('../pages/AllevaLogin.js');
  var AllevaHomeObj = require('../pages/AllevaHome.js');
  var LoginData = require('../testdata/LoginData.js');
  var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

  describe('Checking Alleva Login Functionality', function() {


  using(LoginData.LoginData, function(data, description) {

  it('Login with: '+description, function() {

     AllevaLoginObj.get();

     AllevaLoginObj.login(data.username, data.password, data.answer);

     expect(AllevaHomeObj.isLogoutDisplays());

 })

 });

     afterEach(function() {

       AllevaHomeObj.logout();

  })

});
```

**Conf.js:**

```
  var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter');

  exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    './tests/AllevaLoginTest.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  onPrepare: function() { 

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({

      baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'

    }).getJasmine2Reporter());

   },


  jasmineNodeOpts: {

     onComplete: null,

     isVerbose: true,

     showColors: true,

     includeStackTrace: true,

     defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000
  }
  };
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Also avoid code as images as described here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Hey, I have formatted and added additional info as required, please see.